# How to display the vowels instead of just counting it(vowels)?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here's a code that counts the vowels. How to display the vowels instead of just counting them?.

```
System.out.println("Enter the String:");

String text = we.readLine();

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("The number of vowels in the given String are: " + count);
```

Comment: How did you display the message `The number of vowels in the given String are:`?

Comment: I'm not even entirely sure what you're asking here. Are you wanting to display how many occurrences for each vowel is present?

Comment: instead of counting how many vowels,the output must show the vowels. example "programming" the vowels are: o a i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternate, you can create a char array of vowels, turn the String into a char array and compare each index:

```
char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
String text = "Programming";

for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    for (char vowel : vowels) {
        if (c == vowel) {
            System.out.println(text + " contains the vowel: " + vowel);
        }
     }
}
```